# Thread.start() doesn't call Thread.run() method

Tags: java

In my projects there're 3 classes that extends Thread, each of them does some calculation for integer number. I need to run them to get all three calculated values. This process needs to be done for all integers in a certain range.

This's one of my threads:

```
public class FactorialNumber extends Thread {
private int number;

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    System.out.print(NumbersOperations.getFactorial(number));
}
}
```

That's a method that tries to start threads:

```
public static void getThreevalues() throws InterruptedException {
    int startOfRange = getBorder("Enter the left border of range: ");
    int endOfRange = getBorder("Enter the right border of range: ");
    for(int i = startOfRange; i <= endOfRange; i++) {
        PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber();
        FibonachiNumber fibonachiNumber = new FibonachiNumber();
        FactorialNumber factorialNumber = new FactorialNumber();
        primeNumber.setNumber(i);
        fibonachiNumber.setNumber(i);
        factorialNumber.setNumber(i);
        System.out.print("Number: " + i);
        System.out.print(" is prime number ");
        primeNumber.start();
        System.out.print(". Fibonachi - " );
        fibonachiNumber.start();
        System.out.print(". Factorial - ");
        factorialNumber.start();
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

After running my code I get this:

```
Number: 3 is prime number . Fibonachi - . Factorial - 
Number: 4 is prime number . Fibonachi - . Factorial - 
Number: 5 is prime number . Fibonachi - . Factorial - 
Number: 6 is prime number . Fibonachi - . Factorial - 
true2hi6falsetrue5hi2483falsehi720hi120
```

As I understand, start() does not call run() method. In my run method there's sleep(500), but the result just appears in console without any sleep.

I would appreciate any help, as I've spent too much time on this stuff already and unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, `Thread.start()` calls `Thread.run()`. Maybe the result appears immediately because the threads sleep **after** they print to the console?

Comment: Agree with @proskor, that your Thread.sleep(...) where it's positioned will have no visible effect of any kind. Also you should not extend Thread but rather implement Runnable.

Comment: You seem to be writing code as if `start()` calls `run()` immediately and blocks until it returns. Hint: it doesn't block.

Comment: I changed the order and put sleep before printing th eresult, but anyway result just appear.. the only sleep I see is beforefalse6true23true248false5120720.

Comment: And, as I understood correctly comment of Dark Falcon, you meen that threads run all at the same time and do not wait until the previous ends?

Comment: @LanaGuts, yes, they are made for it!

Comment: @LanaGuts: um, yes, that's what threads do, that's why you use them.

Comment: @LanaGuts, you don't need multithreading here, you only need multithreading when you want things to be done at the same time, if you want things to be done by turn, you do it on the only thread. If you want to learn multithreading on your example, try to make threads for every line of your suggested output. But remember that without syncronisation you will never know the order of that lines

Comment: "try to make threads for every line of your suggested output" I just started learning threads, and I thought that by creating classes that extends Thread and incapsulate some calculation I do what you said. Could you please correct me, so I could do this task with multithreading

Comment: Can someone tell me, if I write code like this primeNumber.start();
        System.out.print(". Fibonachi - " );
        fibonachiNumber.start(); , the string with System.out.println blocks the primeNumber thread? I deleted System.out.print between starting the threadsm and my code finally started working! but , as SpongeBobFan said it needs synchronisation

Comment: No, they are excecuted simultaneously (the main() Thread and your Thread). It is unknown which is going to end first. You have though the sleep method that "delays" your Thread.

Comment: Downvoted as the Lana Guts probably did not read any 5 min tutorial about thread handling otherwise the answer would be trivial. If she did and still did not find out the answer she should look for another job.

Comment: Actually, I've started learning programming from nothing half a year ago, and in my present job I have nothing in common with it. I think it's better to ask a question even when it has an obvious answer for people that know it and become a good professional in the future then to give up on it and then face the problem in real job.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things going on here which will confuse you. Let's start with something that isn't obvious:

`System.out.print()` uses locking to make sure threads don't print over each other. So when you have two threads and one prints `foo` and the other prints `bar`, you can get either `foobar` or `barfoo` but never `fboaro` (= no mixing).

That also means when one thread (the main or one of your three calculation threads) prints something, all other threads that also want to print a the same time, will wait.

Next: Starting threads doesn't queue them. If you start N threads, the system will run all the code of them at the same time. If they all sleep 500ms, then this sleeping will haven in parallel. If you want threads to execute in a certain order, you must use queues and locks.

Lastly: You start the threads but you never wait for the results. So what happens is that the main thread starts the threads and then continues (probably terminates). Then all three threads wait for 500ms at the same time and then they all try to calculate the result and print it at the same time.

As you probably begin to understand, all this is pretty complex and annoying. That's why Java 6 introduced the concurrent framework which solves many of these problems.

In a nutshell, don't create threads anymore. Create `Callables` which return the result you want and then submit them to an `ExecutorService`. The service will run them and return `Future`s. You can then query the future for a result.

This way, you don't have to deal with low-level threading issues, synchronization, locks and queues.

Related:

- [Tutorial for Java Conurrency](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures)

(Edit to allow to remove downvote.)

Comment: Aaron, where did read `System.out.println` is thread safe? There's no mention of thread safety in the docs

Comment: `System.out` uses `PrintStream` which has a lock in all `write()` methods.

Comment: Edit your answer so I can remove the downvote, I learned something today, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are hidden probably in the last String: "true2hi6falsetrue5hi2483falsehi720hi120". All the Threads execute actually the command:

```
System.out.print(NumbersOperations.getFactorial(number));
```

when the loop has ended bacause they have to wait 0,5 seconds. You have also a `print` method to do this, not a `println`, therefore each result is "sticked" to another. As the comments indicate, threads are not excecuted individually, they do not wait namely the end of the previous `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I "played" with sleep and its milliseconds, so some threads didn't have to wait to use print() method, so now that works!

Comment: You have then to accept an answer and particularly the answer which gave you the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

And one moore thing you need to do: wait for the threads to finish. I would expect three calls of `Thread.join()` otherwise your program might end and abort the threads (you did mot mark them as daemon, right?) before they're able to print the result.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you! It helped me to understand threads better. To solve the problem I used method join(), so now the method that starts threads looks like this:

```
public static void getThreevalues() throws InterruptedException {
    int startOfRange = getBorder("Enter the left border of range: ");
    int endOfRange = getBorder("Enter the right border of range: ");
    for(int i = startOfRange; i <= endOfRange; i++) {
        PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber();
        FibonachiNumber fibonachiNumber = new FibonachiNumber();
        FactorialNumber factorialNumber = new FactorialNumber();
        primeNumber.setNumber(i);
        fibonachiNumber.setNumber(i);
        factorialNumber.setNumber(i);
        System.out.print("Number: " + i);
        primeNumber.start();
        primeNumber.join();
        fibonachiNumber.start();
        fibonachiNumber.join();
        factorialNumber.start();
        factorialNumber.join();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // this line's useful to present result by lines
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and my thread classes I didn't change.

Comment: Then, I was too late with my help :-) You should change your code and do the three `start()` first and then the three `join()` statements. Your current actually runs one job after the other without parallelism.